# SQLALCHEMY ORM - error when using variables both for column, value in WHERE

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm little confusing on using orm.

I'm making GET user list function, and adding some conditions on it.
I'm adding ORDER BY, LIMIT, and WHERE condition.

```
stmt = (
            select(
                MbrMember.member_seq,
                MbrMember.member_id,
                MbrMember.member_type_cd,
                MbrMember.member_status_cd,
                MbrMember.member_name,
                MbrMember.member_nick,
                MbrMember.member_memo,
                MbrMember.reg_dt,
                MbrMember.reg_member_seq,
                MbrMember.mod_dt,
                MbrMember.mod_member_seq,
            )
            .order_by(MbrMember.member_seq.asc())
            .limit(row_count)
        )
        if where_column and where_value:
            stmt = stmt.where(getattr(MbrMember, where_column[1:-1]) == where_value)
```

where_column is string so [1:-1] helps to get rid of commas

Code above is my intended code and it should be readed like this:

```
FROM mbr_member 
WHERE mbr_member.member_id = google@google.com
ORDER BY mbr_member.member_seq DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

(if where_column='member_id', where_value='google@google.com', row_count=5)

but it is readed like:

```
FROM mbr_member 
WHERE mbr_member.member_id = $1::VARCHAR 
ORDER BY mbr_member.member_seq DESC 
LIMIT $2::INTEGER
```

row_count in LIMIT and where_value in WHERE is not working well.

As the values are not written well, GET user list function returns like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": {
        "members_total_cnt": 0,
        "members": {}
    }
}
```

The function is returning empty list(even though there is the value in DB) but I can see mistakes in the log.

However, if I give up where_value and write code like below:
`stmt = stmt.where(getattr(MbrMember, where_column) == "email@google.com")`
It works fine. What is the problem and is it possible to solve? thanks

not using where_value in WHERE condition works fine

Comment: What does "not working well" mean? Is there an error? If there is an error, please [edit] the question to add the _complete_ error traceback.  If the query returns unexpected results (or no result), please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ output of `print(repr(where_column))`.

Comment: Also, what does your engine url look like (`print(engine)`)?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the first comment - `print(repr(where_value))`

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for commenting. result of 
print(repr(where_column)) -> "'member_id'"
, so I changed code like 
stmt = stmt.where(getattr(MbrMember, where_column[1:-1]) == where_value). Still not working

Comment: Oh my mistake. Nothing wrong with the sql statement and it works fine!